Movie about Kid finding solace under water
I saw parts of a movie playing on a screen and it seemed really interesting. SO it starts off with this kid who like to keep his head under water in the tub, it seemed like he found solace under water. As he grew up he did the same thing in the pool. Any Idea to what the movie was?
I think it was Hollywood, it was definitely English, looked post 2000's, but I could be wrong. The main kid actor kind of looked like Joaquin Phoenix from gladiator. But he was a kid. That's about all I remember.

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

I think I remember the same scene... but all I can confirm is: yes, as far as I remember it was a Hollywood production. It may have had supernatural elements...

Would almost sound like The Graduate, but that's definitely pre 2000's.  But I'd guess that scene is likely inspired by the one from The Graduate.

You are looking for Percy Jackson & the Olympians: The Lightning Thief.There is a scene where Percy, the title character, sits at the bottom of the school swimming pool. 
The plot of the movie :

In New York City, Zeus and Poseidon meet at the top of the Empire State Building, where Zeus reveals that his master lightning bolt has been stolen and accuses Poseidon's demigod son, Percy Jackson, of the theft. Poseidon reminds him that Percy is unaware of his true identity, but Zeus declares that unless his master bolt is returned to Mount Olympus before the summer solstice, in two weeks' time, war will be waged between all the gods.> Percy is a 16-year-old boy who appears to be dyslexic, but has a unique ability to stay underwater for a long time. While on a school trip to the local museum, Percy is attacked by a Fury disguised as his substitute teacher, who demands the lightning bolt. Percy's best friend, Grover Underwood, and his Latin teacher, Mr. Brunner — both of whom appear disabled — help Percy and scare off the Fury using a pen from Mr. Brunner. Grover tells Percy to use the pen, and Percy discovers that it is a sword. Upon learning of the Fury's reason for the attack, Mr. Brunner has Grover take Percy and his mother Sally to Camp Half-Blood, leaving behind Sally's abusive husband Gabe Ugliano. However, the three are attacked by a minotaur that appears to kill Sally, who is unable to enter the camp. He uses his sword to fight the Minotaur, without initial success. Percy kills the Minotaur with its own horn, then faints from shock.
Three days later, Percy wakes up in the camp. He learns that he is the son of Poseidon, that Grover is a disguised satyr and his protector, and that Mr. Brunner is the centaur Chiron, also initially disguised. Chiron suggests that Percy go to Mount Olympus to convince Zeus of his innocence. Percy begins training to use his demigod powers, which include water manipulation and using water to heal. He also meets other demigods, including Annabeth Chase, daughter of Athena; and Luke Castellan, son of Hermes. After winning a Capture the Flag game, Percy is visited by a fiery apparition of his uncle Hades, who reveals that Sally is with him in theUnderworld and that he will return her safely if Percy hands over the lightning bolt. Defying Chiron's orders, Percy decides to go to the Underworld, joined by Grover and Annabeth. They visit Luke, who gives them a map showing the location of three pearls belonging to Hades' wife, Persephone, which they can use to escape the Underworld. They are also given a pair of winged sneakers Luke stole from his father and a shield Luke describes as his favorite.
The trio heads out, locating the first pearl at an old garden center but encounteringMedusa, who tries to kill them until decapitated by Percy; her head is taken with them for later use. They locate the second pearl in the Parthenon in Nashville; Percy uses the winged shoes to take it from a statue of Athena. However, they are then confronted by the Hydra, which Grover petrifies using Medusa's head. The third pearl is located at the Lotus Casino in Las Vegas, where the three eat lotus flowers and forget their reason for being there. They stay in the casino for five days until Poseidon speaks in Percy's mind, helping Percy return to his senses. Percy frees Grover and Annabeth from the effects of the flowers and they flee, discovering that the casino is run by theLotus-Eaters, and they had been keeping people captive since ancient times. With all three pearls in their possession, Percy, Grover, and Annabeth head into the Underworld, the portal to which is located inHollywood.
In the Underworld, they meet Hades and Persephone. Though Percy tells Hades that he does not have the lightning bolt, Hades finds it hidden inside Luke's shield, revealing that Luke is the lightning thief. Persephone knocks Hades out with the lightning bolt to get back at him for imprisoning her for all eternity and hands the bolt to Percy. However, because they only have three pearls, Grover remains with Persephone to allow Percy's mother to leave. Percy, Annabeth, and Sally teleport to the Empire State Building but are attacked by Luke, who wants to destroy Mount Olympus to secure the demigods' place as the new rulers of the gods. After a fight across Manhattan, Percy defeats Luke and returns the lightning bolt to Zeus, who forgives Percy and allows Poseidon to briefly speak with his son. The film ends with Percy and Annabeth reuniting with Grover, furloughed from Hades and sporting a new pair of small horns that designate his promotion to senior protector. Percy and Annabeth are reunited, and they nearly kiss but Annabeth tricks Percy and they continue to train.
In the post credits-scene, Gabe is kicked out of the apartment. He decides to get a beer but finds a note from Percy saying that he should not open the refrigerator. Gabe breaks the lock anyway and is petrified by Medusa's head inside, though this occurs off-screen as the movie fades to black.

